# Issue with custom malloc implementation

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I am working on a custom malloc and free implementation in C. My code works fine, but not perfectly. In my file that tests my_malloc and my_free, I call my_malloc 3 times. It works for the first 2 calls, but doesn't for the 3rd call. Everything is exactly the same, so I really have no idea why it wouldn't work again. I know there's enough memory in the heap, so it's not that. It even works to the point of returning an address for the pointer variable, but the test file won't write to it.

Here's the bit of code to test my_malloc and my_free, it breaks with c:

```
static int *base;
static int *heap_end;
int total_mem_used = 0;
int first_call = 1;


int i;
int *a, *b, *c;

if ((a=(int *)my_malloc(10))==NULL)
    return MALLOC_FAIL;

for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    a[i] = i;

for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);

if ((b=(int *)my_malloc(18))==NULL)
    return MALLOC_FAIL;

for (i=0;i<18;i++)
    b[i] = i*i;

for (i = 0; i < 18; i++)
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
printf("\n");

if ((c=(int *)my_malloc(5))==NULL)
    return MALLOC_FAIL;

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    c[i] = i*7;
```

Here's my_malloc too, if it helps:

```
void *p;
int *t;
int data_size, block;

if (size==0)
    return NULL;

if (first_call) {
    if ((base=(int *)malloc(HEAP_SIZE))==NULL)
        return NULL;
    init_heap(norm_size(size)+8);
    heap_end = &base[HEAP_SIZE];
    first_call = 0;
    total_mem_used += (norm_size(size)+2);
    t = base;
    return (void *) (t+2);
}

data_size = norm_size(size);
block = data_size + 2;

p = find_first_free(block);

if (p==0) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return NULL;
}

total_mem_used += block;
fill_header((int *) p, block);
t = (int *) p + 2;
return (void *) t;

void my_free(void *p) {
int *t;
t = (int *) p - 2;
*t = *t & -2;
coalesce(t);
}

void *find_first_free(int n) {
int *p;
p = base;

while (p<heap_end && ((*p & 1) || (*p <= n)))
    p = p + (*p & -2);
return (void *)p;
}

int norm_size(int w) {
if (w % 8 == 0)
        return w;
else
        return w + (8 - w % 8);
}

void init_heap(int n) {
base[0] = n+1; // n+1 since we're allocating it
base[1] = (int) &base[n];
base[n-1] = n+1;
base[n] = HEAP_SIZE - n;
base[HEAP_SIZE-1] = HEAP_SIZE - n;
}

 void fill_header(int *p, int w) {
 p[0] = w+1;
 p[1] = (int) &p[w];
 p[w-1] = w+1;
 p[w] = HEAP_SIZE - total_mem_used;
 p[w+HEAP_SIZE-total_mem_used-1] = HEAP_SIZE - total_mem_used;
 }
```

Any idea what exactly is wrong with the program? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Often times that behavior (working several times, then not working) can be caused by something invoking ***[Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)***.  But it could also be caused by failure to re-initialize variables properly between calls.  It would be good if you could provide more specific information regarding the exact error you are seeing.  (by the way, I am Not the down voter)

Comment: post the header to `my_malloc()`, definition of `first_call`, `base`, `heap_end`, ...

Comment: `block = data_size + 2;` --> `block = data_size + sizeof(int);`  `t = (int *) p + 2;` --> `t = (int *) p + 1;`   (The last past is likely the issue - pointer addition versus int addition)

Comment: When I try to print out my c array, all I get is blank spaces. The program doesn't actually stop running or give me an error, it just doesn't assign the proper values to c.

Comment: How do you _try to print out my c array_? A `%d` conversion could not produce only _blank spaces_.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Avoid magic numbers

---

```
block = data_size + 2;
```

Why 2? why not 16 or 256?  Certainly the addition is done to provide for saving the size.  In that case, add the size of the `int`.

```
block = data_size + sizeof(int);
```

---

```
t = (int *) p + 2;
```

Why 2 versus any other number?  Again, this is done to account for the size begin saved at `p`.  But this is not integer addition like before.  This is "pointer addition".  With `+ 2`, `p` is increased by the `2 * sizeof(int)`.  Likely code should be

```
t = p + 1;
```

This is an exception to the "no magic numbers" rule: -1,0,+1 are OK

---

To answer more, post complete functions.

---

Minor: cast not needed

```
// if ((base=(int *)malloc(HEAP_SIZE))==NULL)
if ((base = malloc(HEAP_SIZE)) == NULL)
```

Minor: Consider the unsigned type `size_t`.  That is the type returned by functions/operators like `strlen()`, sizeof()

```
// int data_size
size_t data_size
// if ((a=(int *)my_malloc(10))==NULL)
a = my_malloc(10);
if (a == NULL)
```

Why 8 in `init_heap(norm_size(size)+8);`?  Use a constant/define

```
#define MY_MALLOC_GUARD (8)
init_heap(norm_size(size) + MY_MALLOC_GUARD);
```

Comment: I take `t = p + 2`, because I save the address of the next block at p[1]. So, t is where the user can start inputting their own data. Same reason I'm taking `block = data_size + 2`, but that might make more sense with `block = data_size + 2*sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @LGraup  Again, suggest avoiding magic numbers.  If code had `struct block_T { int size, struct block_T *next, char data[]; }`, Then the offset and address could be computed direct from that.  This would also insure proper alignment. It comes down to the code's robustness/portability needs.